# Simple Javascript Grocery List

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple grocery list, that would prompt for the items and the price, without arrays or functions only using loops. So far, I am having trouble asking for the prices. Here is part of the code.

```js
var count = 0;
var groceryItems = ("Enter the grocery items (or DONE to exit)", "")
while (groceryItems != "DONE") {
  count++
  groceryItems = prompt("Enter the grocery items (or DONE to exit)", "")
}
```

How do I ask for the price of each item the user enters?

Comment: You could use `prompt` again to ask for a price. But this is a really unfriendly way to structure a user interface. Seems like you're just porting imperative C/C++ code. A better way to do this would be with HTML forms and then get the values from the HTML inputs on change or form submission.

Answer (score 1):

I mean you have to store their answers somewhere, right?
But if you just want the answers to be open ended, and store whatever they enter over and over again...

```js
var count = 0;
var groceryItems = [];
var food=true;
//get rid out the count<5 if you want the user to be allowed to enter food forever
 while (food && count<5) {
      count++
  
      food= prompt("Enter the grocery items (or Cancel to exit)","");
      if(food){
        var price=prompt("Enter the price (or Cancel to exit)","");
        groceryItems.push(food+" $"+price);
      }
}

//when you hit cancel all the entered items will be alerted.
alert(groceryItems.join(','));
```

Also this probably shouldn't be a public facing user interface design.